# Is there a way to get the type of the current class in a static context?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, static, decltype

Out of curiosity, is it possible to get the type of the current class without spelling out its name in a static context?

The idea was something like this:

```
class Foo{
    auto clone () -> decltype(*this);
}
```

But this does only work in non-static contexts. Member declarations like these are not possible:

```
class Foo{
    static auto make() -> decltype(*this); //"this" is not valid in a static function
    decltype(*this) secondFoo;
    static decltype(*this) instance;
}
```

So, is there something I can replace `decltype(*this)` with that would make the above declarations valid?

---

A workaround is of course to `typedef Foo OwnType;` and then use `OwnType`, I'm just curious if there are also different ways.

---

I would like to do that for a PMP function that defines a load of static member variables that are of the same type as the class the function is called in.